# DSP Topic for Newcomers

Tags: fft

Does any one of you know what topic to teach people related to signal processing.
The audience is mainly for a group of software programmer working on a telecommunication product who have limited knowledge of signal processing.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the  most fundamental things that anybody trying to understand DSP should know are:

1. Nyqvist Sampling Theorem and Effects of Aliasing
2. Need for DFT and the use of FFT to achieve the same.
3. Basics of Digital Filters.

You have mentioned the audience as telecommunication engineers. So you could also add a lecture on the  need for modulation,some basic modulation and demodulation techniques and need for interpolation and decimation.

Answer (score 0):

"Limited knowledge" could take on quite a range of values.

I would try to relate DSP topics to concepts they are familiar with. For example, they surely understand the concept of a histogram, so relate that to an FFT. Or relate a moving average to a low pass filter.

Apply some filtering to a popular musical clip so they can hear the effects. Or take an FFT of some data they are familiar with, preferably some data with a cyclical event occurring, and show how that event appears in the spectrum.